# How to Perform a Join Operation with a Group by In EF CORE

Tags: c#, sql, join, group-by, ef-core-2.2

I have two tables Clients and ClientEvaluations, those tables are connected through a foreign key. Each ClientEvaluation has FK to a single Client Entity.

Now i need to query all clients with their last evaluation, no more than one valuation per client. Note that each evaluation has a date.

This code here achieves that in SQL.

```
SELECT C.Id, MAX(E.EvaluationDate) FROM [dbo].[Clients] as C

JOIN [dbo].[ClientEvaluations] AS E ON E.ClientId = C.Id

GROUP BY C.Id
```

I have also tried this but the problem with what I'm trying to achieve is that i need to get back from this query the Client entity properties as well.

```
var lastEvaluations = _db.ClientEvaluations.GroupBy(x => x.ClientId, (x, y) => new { ClientId = x, EvaluationDate = y.Max(z => z.EvaluationDate), }).ToList();
```

But the query here of course only returns the ClientId and the date, how can i include the whole client entity?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have [configured _dbContext correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships). Then you can use include to do the join operation.

```
var results = _dbcontext
                .Clients
                .Include(x => x.ClientEvaluations) //join
                .GroupBy(y => y.Id) // group by
                .Select(z => new 
                   {
                       Id = z.Key.Value,
                       Max = z.Max(x => x.EvaluationDate),
                   }).ToList();
```

Or

```
var results =   from c in _dbcontext.Clients
                join e in _dbcontext.ClientEvaluations
                on c.Id equals e.ClientId
                group c by c.Id into cg
                select new
                {
                    Id = Id = cg.FirstOrDefault().Id,
                    Max = cg.Max(x => x.EvaluationDate),
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Well as far as i know the context is correct. The problem with what I'm trying to achieve is that i need to get back from this query the Client entity properties as well.

`var lastEvaluations = _db.ClientEvaluations.GroupBy(x => x.ClientId, (x, y) => new
      {
        ClientId = x,
        EvaluationDate = y.Max(z => z.EvaluationDate),
      }).ToList();`
But the query here of course only returns the ClientId and the date, how can i include the whole client entity..?

Comment: Please include this in question.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to achieve the above?